# Tensor Flow 2 Object Detection API2 Batch Non Max Suppression in trained Faster-RCNN network on TPU does not seem to work. Is this a bug?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I followed the new Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API 2 documentation to train a Faster RCNN detector using transfer learning on Google Cloud Platform TPU. After the training is completed, I dowloaded the result on my workstation and exported the model using the tensorflow 2 implementation ('object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py'). I followed the official instructions and setup the environment locally (running on macOS catalina, tensorflow 2.2, python 3.6 etc)

However the Non-Max-Supprersion (NMS) part of the inference pipeline seems not to be working as there are cases where bounding boxes of different classes overlap almost completed. I debugged the code to ensure that the object detection api implementation of NMS (batch_multiclass_non_max_suppression method in object_detection/core/post_processing.py) is called in the inference pipeline for the Faster-RCNN model. It is called twice as expected by the Fast-RCNN architecture on inference.

The instructions I used for GCPs AI-Platform TPU, are the ones in the official object detection api page: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_training_and_evaluation.md). I made corrections in the training parameters to use the TPU runtime and Python version that are supported on GCP as the actual example are not supported. Instead I used:

gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training `whoami`*object_detection*`date +%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S` 
--job-dir=gs://${MODEL_DIR} 
--package-path ./object_detection 
--module-name object_detection.model_main_tf2 
--runtime-version 2.2 
--python-version 3.7 
--scale-tier BASIC_TPU 
--region us-central1 
-- 
--use_tpu true 
--model_dir=gs://${MODEL_DIR} 
--pipeline_config_path=gs://${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH}

The dataset I used for training was the Pets example from the official object detection api page:  [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md). However I exported it using the Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API 2 methods for consistency.

The pre-trained neural network I uses was the [Faster R-CNN ResNet101 V1 1024x1024](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz) trained on TPU.

The configuration file I used was [faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8.config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/configs/tf2/faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8.config) for TPU training.
I changed the number of classes to 37.
I also changed the number of batches to batch_size: 32 as gpc on tpu v2 was crashing.
The fine_tune_checkpoint_type was changed to fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection" and the only data augmentation I used was random_horizontal_flip.

The [official object detection 2 model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) reports results on TPU trained architectures other than SSD.
However the [official object detection tpu compatibility guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tpu_compatibility.md) mentions that currently SSD is only supported while non max suppression is not.

Why NMS is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because the `batch_multiclass_non_max_suppression` method is a class-aware NMS (or at least is what I understood). This means that, for each class, among all the boxes that belong to the **same class** with IOUs greater than a threshold only the box with the highest score is retained.

I think you want a class-agnostic NMS (`use_class_agnostic_nms: True`). Moreover, if you want one class for detection you should also set `max_classes_per_detection: 1`.